# Как в sqlite обновить сразу несколько записей?

Tags: php, sqlite

Как в sqlite обновить сразу несколько записей в таблице и одним обращением к файлу?

Сравнение по `id` и `alter` . Обновить поля `title` и `text`

```
$items = [
  [
  'id' => 21,
  'alter' => 345,
  'title' => 'Заголовок',
  'text' => 'Текст'
  ],[
  'id' => 23,
  'alter' => 875,
  'title' => 'Заголовок 2',
  'text' => 'Текст 2'
  ],
  ...
];
```

Нужно сделать для `php`

Answer (score 1):

Это обновит все записи в таблице:

```
UPDATE my_table SET text='new_text'
```

Так же вы можете добавить условие, по которому нужно обновить записи. Это обновит все записи, поле `text` которых начинается на `Текст`

```
UPDATE my_table SET text='new_text' WHERE text LIKE 'Текст%'
```

Comment: А если к примеру нужно обновить миллион записей, получается в цикле он будет миллион раз перезаписывать файл на жестком диске?

Comment: @Squeli47 не будет он миллион раз перезаписывать. Вообще странная ситуация, когда вы обновляете сразу миллион записей. Во-первых при нормальной работе БД такой необходимости не должно возникать. Во-вторых `sqlite` не предназначен для больших объёмов данных. Если у вас будет несколько миллионов записей возьмите что-то помощнее, например, `postgresql`